# Open PDF file and save it in temporary location in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file in a file system. I am using `open($file_path)->getContents()` and am able to get some text but I am trying to find a way to store this in a temporary path in Php.

I need to upload the PDF file in the same file system with a different access point. Is there any way that I can just read/open the PDF file and then save as a PDF again in a different path or is there any way around this ?

In Short I need to read a PDF file to upload in a file system as a PDF file.

Comment: Sorry, but I personally cannot figure out what you need here. If it's a PHP question .. then I do not see what it has to do with PhpStorm; If it's a PhpStorm question -- then what is the question? The way how you've described it did not made it easy to understand...

Comment: @LazyOne I just edited my question. Please ignore phpstorm.

Comment: is this just a case of moving/copying the file from one folder to another? Or do you actually need to send it between two entirely separate servers? The wording is not very clear. You say "upload" but then also say "same file system". If it's the same file system, then no upload would be required, it's just a move or copy operation.

Answer (score 2):

To read file use `file_get_contents` or `fopen`

To write to file use `file_put_contents` or `fwrite`

So to re-locate file:

```
file_put_contents('/new/path', file_get_content('/old/path'));
```

*or*

just use [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function

```
copy('/old/path', '/new/path');
```